# xerces-c 3.1 XPath evaluation

Tags: xpath, xerces-c

I could not find much examples of evaluate XPath using xerces-c 3.1.

Given the following sample XML input:

```
<abc> 
    <def>AAA BBB CCC</def>
</abc>
```

I need to retrieve the "AAA BBB CCC" string by the XPath "/abc/def/text()[0]".

The following code works:

```
XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
// create the DOM parser
XercesDOMParser *parser = new XercesDOMParser;
parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Never);
parser->parse("test.xml");
// get the DOM representation
DOMDocument *doc = parser->getDocument();
// get the root element
DOMElement* root = doc->getDocumentElement();

// evaluate the xpath
DOMXPathResult* result=doc->evaluate(
    XMLString::transcode("/abc/def"), // "/abc/def/text()[0]"
    root,
    NULL,
    DOMXPathResult::ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, //DOMXPathResult::ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, //DOMXPathResult::STRING_TYPE,
    NULL);

// look into the xpart evaluate result
result->snapshotItem(0);
std::cout<<StrX(result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->getNodeValue())<<std::endl;;

XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
return 0;
```

But I really hate that:

```
result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->getNodeValue()
```

Has it to be a node set instead of the exact node I want?

I tried other format of XPath such as "/abc/def/text()[0]", and "DOMXPathResult::STRING_TYPE". xerces always thrown exception.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't code with Xerces C++ but it seems to implement the W3C DOM Level 3 so based on that I would suggest to select an element node with a path like `/abc/def` and then simply to access `result->getNodeValue()->getTextContent()` to get the contents of the element (e.g. `AAA BBB CCC`).

As far as I understand the DOM APIs, if you want a string value then you need to use a path like `string(/abc/def)` and then `result->getStringValue()` should do (if the `evaluate` method requests any type or STRING_TYPE as the result type).

Other approaches if you know you are only interested in the first node in document order you could evaluate `/abc/def` with `FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE` and then access `result->getNodeValue()->getTextContent()`.

Comment: result->getStringValue() always throw, no matter what TYPE is passed into the evaluate(). result->getNodeValue()->getTextContent() works. Thanks

Comment: It will be great to have an XPath to make the result->getStringValue() work. Anybody knows how?

Comment: @JohnCrane Is there a way to know if a document is owned by a parser?. 
Can you please have a look at this question..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673300/how-to-know-if-a-domdocument-is-created-using-a-parser

Comment: Xerces does not support string return type xpaths: https://github.com/apache/xerces-c/blob/4bac3c53e44506591c2892cc19f0452be169b401/src/xercesc/dom/impl/DOMXPathExpressionImpl.cpp#L119