# How to know if a DOMDocument is owned by a parser

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument, xerces

I am looking into an issue where an API is getting called from two different sources.
We have an API called dispatch. Its signature is as follows.

```
DOMDocument* dispatch( DOMDocument * requestDocument )
```

We observed that this API can be called by passing a DOMDocument object that is

1. A stand-alone DOMDocument object created using DOMImplementation::createDocument
   http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMImplementation.html
2. A parse owned DOMDocument object created using AbstractDOMParser::getDocument
   http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classAbstractDOMParser.html#143bc9285686b49f0f06a184b079292a

If i created a document using approach 1, it wont be owned by the parser. However, if i create it using approach 2, it would be owned by the parser.

My question is, if i have a document, how would i know whether it is owned by a parser or not?.

Can you please help me on this or point me to some resource. I am exploring as we speak.

Thanks,
PAvan.

Answer (score 0):

They're *both* the result of parsing.

Comment: But isnt the document in one case 'owned by the parser' and the second case the document is 'stand-alone' ?.

I want to capture this difference..